# Bootstrap modal with multiple images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, modal-dialog

I have images in different albums. When I click on the album cover image I have to see in modal first image of the album and after pressing the button next to see next image.

Problem is that when I click on the cover image I see all images in the album ( in my case two images one below the other). I am getting the images from get_images.php file like this:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){                  
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $i = 'images/'.$row['GalleryName']; 
        $img .= "<img src='$i' class='img-responsive' alt=''/>";

    }
}
```

Code in my index page is:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="dynamic-content">
                    <img src="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Script for getting the pictures and retrieve them is this:

```
function getImages(album_id) {

    $.getJSON('get_images.php?album_id=' + album_id,function(data)
        {
             $('#dynamic-content img').html(data.img);
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
}
```

[This is how I see modal!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQAYI.jpg)

What is wrong - CSS, HTML, Javascript or all of them?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap version 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to [read the Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/).

There are several fixes required in your code. The image class should be `img-fluid`, not `img-responsive`. The `modal-body` should be inside the `modal-content`. The img should be in the `modal-body`. You should only use `row` with the grid columns (`col-*`). There are no glyphicons in Bootstrap 4.

https://www.codeply.com/go/rvvjHtENYT

```
<div class="modal bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="dynamic-content">
                    <img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

If you want multiple images in the `modal-body`, the structure should be like this..

```
<div class="modal-body" id="dynamic-content">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col"><img src=".." class="img-fluid" alt=""/></div>
            <div class="col"><img src=".." class="img-fluid" alt=""/></div>
            <div class="col"><img src=".." class="img-fluid" alt=""/></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. It was some mix of different codes and become a little mess :) I will read more about this why I have these two images in my modal not just one.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the result after my last changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxDmA.png)

in get_images.php I changed it to return (im my case I have two div's):

```
    <div class='col'><img src='$i' class='img-fluid' alt=''/></div>
```

In html I have:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="row" id="dynamic-content">

         </div>
    </div>
```

And js for pasing result inside  is:

```
      $.get('get_images.php?album_id=' + album_id,function(data)
      {

          $('#dynamic-content').html(data);
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
      });
```

I cannot understand why is this happend?